# Protocol requirement cannot be satisfied

Tags: swift, protocols

I would like to create a protocol for view on watchOS, iOS and TvOS, so I can get their subviews and superviews in a generic way.

At first I tried this :

```
protocol ViewProtocol: Hashable {
    var superview: Self? { get }
    var subviews: [Self] { get }
}
```

And then I extend the `UIView` class like this :

```
extension UIView: ViewProtocol {}
```

But I get this error from the compiler:

`<unknown>:0: error: protocol 'ViewProtocol' requirement 'superview' cannot be satisfied by a non-final class ('UIView') because it uses 'Self' in a non-parameter, non-result type position`

I'm not sur to understand the problem (I think it's related to the compiler not being able to use Self in a non final class), so I tried the following :

The protocol would look like this :

```
protocol ViewProtocol: Hashable {
    func getSuperview() -> ViewProtocol?
    func getSubviews() -> [ViewProtocol]
}
```

But now I get this error at the protocol declaration :

`Protocol 'ViewProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

So I tried this :

```
protocol ViewProtocol: Hashable {
    func getSuperview<T: ViewProtocol>() -> T?
    func getSubviews<T: ViewProtocol>() -> [T]
}
```

And the implementation look like this:

```
extension UIView: ViewProtocol {
    func getSuperview<T>() -> T? where T : ViewProtocol {
        return self.superview as! T?
    }

    func getSubviews<T>() -> [T] where T : ViewProtocol {
        return self.subviews as! [T]
    }
}
```

But now when I try to use the method on generic type `ViewProtocol` I get this error : `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`

Can someone help me ? I would like to fundamentally understand what's going on here and why it is so difficult to make that work ?

Comment: `Protocol 'ViewProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements` somes from the `==` operator of `Equatable`, which has `Self` requirements

Comment: Ok so that means that I cannot do, with swift, create a protocol like I want (subview/superview) and at the same time being hashable ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're going after with this protocol, so I can't really answer that. The semantics of the first bit of code is "If I'm an `XView`, then I have a `superview` of type `XView`, and I have subviews that are all also `XView`. Such a protocol would be completely useless. For example, a table view could only have table view parent and child views. That makes no sense.

Comment: Actually I want to get the view hierarchy of a View (that could be a UIView or a NSView, hence the protocol)

Comment: Try dropping the hashable part until you get the rest sorted, then you can add hashable conformance back in, and make the necessary type eraser for it

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `Self` requirement in non-final classes, and here's an example to illustrate why that wouldn't make sense:

```
protocol Copyable {
    var copyOfSelf: Self { get }
}

final class Car {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
}

extension Car: Copyable {
    var copyOfSelf: Car { return Car(name: self.name) }
}

class SportsCar: Car {
    // Inherited:
    // var copyOfSelf: Car { return Car(name: self.name) }
    // Notice that it still returns `Car`, not `SportsCar`,
    // Breaking the conformance to `Copyable`
}
```